# Is it possible to set GOPROXY=/file.. in Linux

Tags: go, goproxy

I'm having a trouble mapping some go modules imported from github.com locally in an offline environment. I thought of changing GOPROXY into a file path, that contains the folder of the previously installed packages. Is that possible?

Thanks!

OS: Linux

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

You can set the  `GOPROXY` to the target directory as an example to the directory: `file://C:/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/download`

For more info: see [this thread](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27698)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your response I'm glad to know that it is possible. I see you responded with windows path structure what about Linux? kindly, let me know if you have any idea?

Comment: @MAl, why wouldn't it work with a unix path? (It is probably more useful to link to the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Module_proxy_protocol) rather than a closed GitHub issue specifically about windows)